# How to declare iterable object of another interface type?

Tags: typescript

So, here I'm trying to make interface type of Object which will contain only specific interfaces in it. For example:

```
export interface IUser {
  name: string;
  last: string;
};

export interface IRoom {
  users: Object<IUser>; // this is wrong.
}
```

I'm expecting, that users will be something like:

```
Users: {
  'user_id_goes_here': {
    name: 'John',
    last: 'Doe'
  },
  'user_id_goes_here': {
    name: 'Albert',
    last: 'Einstein'
  },
  ...
}
```

Is there any way to define interface member type like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
export interface Room {
    users: UserMap;
}

export interface UserMap {
    [userId: string]: User;
}

export interface User {
    name: string;
    last: string;
}
```

That `[userId: string]: IUser;` is what's called a *string index signature*. It means that whenever you use a string to index into a `UserMap`, you will get an `IUser`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was not sure what I should search in google though. Now I remember it's a map type.

Comment: Sure, index signatures are meant to model map-like objects in JavaScript, but it's not obvious what they'd be called. Hopefully someone searching finds this answer. As a heads up, if all you're using these for is the type, you can use an `interface` declaration instead of a `class` (since `interface`s don't have any emit).

Comment: You're right. I forgot to mention the interface, it was quickly written example without much thinking and was tired. Thanks for advise! P.S edited the question, replaced class with interface.